# DJANGO - [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/media'

Tags: python, django, media

I get an error regarding Media directory on Django.

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Mots
from django import forms


class CreeMot(ModelForm):
    mot = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = forms.IntegerField(max_value=10)
    image = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Mots
        fields = ["mot", "level", "image"]
```

**views.py**

```
def cree_mot(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreeMot(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = CreeMot()
    return render(request, "cp/cree_mot.html", {'form': form})
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# Add these new lines
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles', 'media_root')
```

When the form is submitted I get this error:

```
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/media'
```

Actually my `/media/` directory is at the same level of `/static/`:

```
cp
  /views.py
  /forms.py
main_app
  /settings.py
  /...
media
static
manage.py
```

I put my `/media/` in 777 chmod.

Answer (score 0):

You should erase and leave just basics staff to understand what is going on in your app. In your case firstly, remove

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles', 'media_root')
```

and leave just path to your path to media like :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'path/to/media'
```

Hope it will help for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is just a debugging step, not an actual solution. `Post Answer` should only be used for complete answers to the problem. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); for now, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30231555)